# Two SQL Queries - Performance difference?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm using MySQL with PDO in PHP and I have a SQL query, which works as expected. However, I care about performance and would like to know if I could **improve** my query. I'm also asking, because I want to **gain** some more **background knowledge** of **SQL**.

Let's say I have two tables that have a **few equal fields** (and some **additional information**, which are **different** in each table):

```
table `blog_comments`: id, userid (int) | timestamp (int) | content (varchar) | other
table `projects_comments`: id, userid (int) | timestamp (int) | content (varchar) | other
```

The field `id` is the **primary key**, `userid + timestamp` have an **index** in both tables, and timestamp is simply the unixtime with the length of 10 (integer).

As a simple spam protection, I block a user from submitting a new comment (no matter if blog, project or anything else) until 60 seconds have passed since his last comment. To achieve this, I get the **latest timestamp** of that user from **all** the comments tables.

This is my **working** query:

```
SELECT MAX(`last_timestamp`) AS `last_timestamp`
FROM
(
    SELECT `userid`, max(`timestamp`) AS `last_timestamp`
    FROM `blog_comments`
    GROUP BY `userid`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `userid`, max(`timestamp`) as `last_timestamp`
    FROM `projects_comments`
    GROUP BY `userid`
) AS `subquery`
WHERE `userid` = 1
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

As you can notice, I use **GROUP BY** inside the **subqueries**, and in the **main query** I simply **filter** the **userid** (in this case: 1). The advantage: I just need to **pass** the **userid once** as a parameter.

Now, I am interested into how SQL exactly works. I think it will be like this: SQL first performs the subqueries, groups **all** the **existing rows** by userid and **returns the whole set** to the main query, which then applies the where clause to find the required userid. This seems like a big leak of performance to me.

So I thought on slightly **changing the query**:

```
SELECT max(`last_timestamp`) AS `last_timestamp`
FROM
(
    SELECT max(`timestamp`) AS `last_timestamp`
    FROM `blog_comments`
    WHERE `userid` = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT max(`timestamp`) as `last_timestamp`
    FROM `projects_comments`
    WHERE `userid` = 1
) AS `subquery`
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Now I have to pass the userid twice, and still the whole set of rows will be looked up for the given userid. I am not sure if this really **improves** the performance.

I don't have any large data amount yet to really test it, maybe I will do some test scenarios later. I would be really interested into knowing if there would be a difference, when there would be many data sets in those tables?

Would appreciate any ideas, information and tips, thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

MySQL explain of the **first** query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   Using where
2   DERIVED     blog_comments   range   NULL    userid  8   NULL    10  Using index for group-by
3   UNION   projects_comments   index   NULL    userid  12  NULL    6   Using index
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union2,3>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

MySQL explain of the **second** query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2    
2   DERIVED     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Select tables optimized away
3   UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Select tables optimized away
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union2,3>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that the second should perform better in MySQL than the first, for exactly the reason you gave.  MySQL will run the full `group by` on all the data and *then* select the one group.

You can see the different in execution paths by putting an `explain` in front of the query.  That will give ou some idea of what the query is really doing.

If you have an index on `user_id, timestamp`, then the second query will run quite fast, only using the index.  Even without an index, the second query would do a full table scan of the two tables -- and that is it.  The first will do a full table scan and a file sort for the aggregation.  The second takes longer.

If you wanted to pass in the `userid` only once, you could do something like:

```
select coalesce(greatest(bc_last_timestamp, pc_last_timestamp),
                bc_last_timestamp, pc_last_timestamp
               )
from (select (SELECT max(`timestamp`) FROM `blog_comments` bc where bc.userid = const.userid
             ) bc_last_timestamp,
             (SELECT max(`timestamp`) FROM `projects_comments` pc where pc.userid = const.userid
             ) pc_last_timestamp
      from (select 1 as userid) const
     ) t;
```

The query looks arcane but it should optimize similarly to your second one.

Comment: Indeed, that query looks arcane hehe, but I see how it works. Thanks for reminding me on the `explain` feature. Now I see, in the first query the `WHERE` is executed first - does that mean the `GROUP BY` will already mention the given `userid`?

Comment: @Francodi . . . No.  I removed it.  It was code detritus as I was editing the code.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the first of my two mentioned queries in my question. `explain` shows me that the `WHERE` of the main query is executed before `MySQL` goes into the `subqueries`, that's why I ask if the `userid` will be considered in the `GROUP BY` already?

Comment: @Francodi . . . Edit your question and post the explain plan.

Comment: edited it (at the end of the question) -> hope it's readable, if not I will edit it again. I see, that I forgot to mention the primary key (an unique id for each comment), but I thought it wouldn't be considered in that query?

Comment: Sorry, updated my question again, the indexes were not set properly. Now there are both explain paths.

Comment: Notice `Select tables optimized away`. That's because you're selecting a specific row that's indexed.

Comment: Yes, I created an index for `userid, timestamp` (before it was only `userid`)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative approach...

```
SELECT 'It''s been more than 1 minute since your last post' As result
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   blog_comments
         WHERE  userid = 1
         AND    timestamp > Date_Sub(Current_Timestamp, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
       )
AND    NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   projects_comments
         WHERE  userid = 1
         AND    timestamp > Date_Sub(Current_Timestamp, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
       )
```

There will be a result if `userid` = `1` hasn't got a timestamped record within the last minute in either table.

You can also swap the logic around...

```
SELECT 'You''re not allowed to post just yet...' As result
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   blog_comments
         WHERE  userid = 1
         AND    timestamp > Date_Sub(Current_Timestamp, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
       )
OR     EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   projects_comments
         WHERE  userid = 1
         AND    timestamp > Date_Sub(Current_Timestamp, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
       )
```

This second option will probably be more efficient (`EXISTS` vs `NOT EXISTS`) but that's for you to test and prove ;)

Comment: +1 for exists and for hitting the index on timestamp.  However, shouldn't it be timestamp > Date_Sub ... ?

Comment: That's an interesting and nice solution and avoids any further caluclations on the `PHP` side too. The performance will be equal to the second query in my question I think?

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths yes it should indeed. Amended.

Comment: @gvee I accepted Gordons answer as it was more related to the performance question. But I really appreciate your approach, it's a great idea, thanks!